# How to plot two functions together in Maple

Tags: maple

I'm given two functions (a surface and a tangent plane), and I am required to plot them together in the same graph in Maple.

The surface is $$x^2y^2+y^2z^2+z^2x^2=15$$ and the tangent plane is $$z=\frac{9}{2}-\frac{5}{4}x-\frac{5}{4}y$$

I have used

```
 implicitplot3d
```

to plot the surface, and

```
 plot3d
```

to plot the tangent plane separately.

My question is, how do I plot these two functions together in the same graph?

Comment: p1:= plot (function1 , options ) : 
p2:= plot ( function2, options ) :
display(p1,p2) ;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were on a right path:

```
[> with(plots):
   implicitplot3d([x^2*y^2+x^2*z^2+y^2*z^2 = 15, z = 9/2-(5/4)*x-(5/4)*y], x = -6 .. 6, y = -6 .. 6, z = -6 .. 6, numpoints = 10000, style = surface, color = [blue, red]);
```

[image]

[image]